# Modifying dots (...) inside a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to modify the dots (...) inside a custom function. Here's a simplified example of my `plot2` function, which displays a plot onscreen with `type="p"` (the default) and saves an svg with `type="l"`. The problem surfaces when one of the `...` plot options is already in the function. In this example, `"type"` is matched by multiple actual arguments.

```
plot2 <-function(...){
plot(...) #visible on screen

svg("c:/temp/out.svg") #saved to file
plot(...,type="l")
dev.off()
}

#This works
plot2(1:10)
#This does not work because type is redefined
plot2(1:10, type="o")
```

I have tried to put the dots in a `list` inside the function and modify it, but `plot` does not accept a list as an input.

```
#Does not work
plot2 <-function(...){
plot(...)

dots <<-list(...)
print(dots)
if("type" %in% names(dots)) dots$type="l"
print(dots)

svg("c:/temp/out.svg")
plot(dots)
dev.off()
}
plot2(1:10, type="o")
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In cases where you want to forward a modified version of `...`, you need to do two things:

1. *Capture* the dots
2. *Forward* the captured dots via [`do.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html).

This works as follows:

```
plot2 = function (...) {
    # capture:
    dots = list(...)

    # modify:
    dots$type = 'l'

    # forward call:
    do.call(plot, dots)
}
```

In general, `do.call(f, list(‹…›))` is equivalent to `f(‹…›)`.

Comment: Thank you. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, there is a simpler (and better) way, and you do not need to touch to `...`. By explicitly defining the arguments that need a special treatment, you take them out of the catch all `...`. This is also a sane approach that is more explicit about what the function does (in its formal arguments). Here is how to do it:

```
plot2 <- function(x, type = "p", ...) {
  plot(x, type = type, ...) #visible on screen

  svg("out.svg") #saved to file
  plot(x, ..., type = "l")
  dev.off()
}

plot2(1:10)
plot2(1:10, type = "o")
```

Comment: The example I provided is simplified and your solution wouldn't be optimal with my actual functions. In my real life example, the `plot` function is a custom plot function with close to 50 arguments. The `plot2` function is just a wrapper to display the plot and save it in several formats.

Comment: Sorry, but still, it does work. It is not all the arguments that can be passed to ..., but only the few arguments you are manipulating in  special way in your function that must be explicitly taken out of ...