# How to overwrite a hardcoded function argument with the dots (...) parameter?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a plot function with a set of default values and the flexibility to change these values by using any argument the `plot` function accepts inside the dots (`...`) argument. An example:

```
PlotIt <- function(x, y, ...) {
  plot(x, y, type = "l", asp = 1, ...)
}

x <- 1:10
y <- 10:1

PlotIt(x = x, y = y)
# Returns a plot
PlotIt(x = x, y = y, asp = NA)
# Error in plot.default(x, y, type = "l", asp = 1, ...) : 
#  formal argument "asp" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

The error is naturally because I try to pass the asp argument twice into `plot`. So far my best clumsy attempt is to make an if-else statement to take this into account (the approach is modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259346/how-to-get-names-of-dot-dot-dot-arguments-in-r)):

```
PlotIt2 <- function(x, y, ...) {

  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)

  if(names(mc$...) %in% "asp") {
  plot(x, y, type = "l", ...)  
  } else {
  plot(x, y, type = "l", asp = 1, ...)  
  }

}

PlotIt2(x = x, y = y, asp = NA)
# works
```

To do this for all possible parameters one can set in with the `...` argument, I would need to write a long if-else statement. **Is there a more elegant way of doing this?**

The question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159520/modifying-dots-inside-a-function) with the difference that I want to automatically overwrite all parameters set by the `...` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use base R only,
you can put everything in a list and remove duplicates based on the argument names
(making sure that the defaults are last so that they are removed if they are present in `...`):

```
PlotIt <- function(x, y, ...) {
  arguments <- list(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    ...,
    type = "l",
    asp = 1
  )

  arguments <- arguments[!duplicated(names(arguments))]

  do.call("plot", arguments)
}
```

If you don't mind depending on [`rlang`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rlang),
you could also do the following,
using `.homonyms` to get the same functionality
(and check the plot's labels for the axes,
it'll be different between the base R and `rlang` versions):

```
PlotIt <- function(x, y, ...) {
  require("rlang")
  arguments <- rlang::dots_list(
    rlang::expr(x),
    rlang::expr(y),
    ...,
    type = "l",
    asp = 1,
    .homonyms = "first"
  )

  call <- rlang::call2("plot", !!!arguments)
  eval(call)
}
```

Comment: would you also be able to use `match.call()` in this example to solve the problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486753/why-is-match-call-useful/)? Im trying to learn about `match.call()` but I prefer your approach, its more intuitive

Comment: @user63230 well, what Mikko attempted in his question is what I can think of, I'm not sure how to improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding your argument in the plot function, set an argument within your function's parameters with a default value equal to your previously hardcoded value. To make life easy, use the same name as the plot argument:

```
PlotIt <- function(x, y, asp = 1, ...) {
  plot(x, y, type = "l", asp = asp, ...)
}
```

Because you defined a default parameter asp = 1, you can choose to

```
x <- 1:10; y <- 10:1
PlotIt(x = x, y = y) # not enter the parameter
PlotIt(x = x, y = y, asp = NA) # or enter the parameter
```

and it will work as desired.